# Center brand in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap 3.0 and can't for the life of me figure out how to center the brand image in the navbar.

**http://jsbin.com/efagoj/99/edit?html,output**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: orange;">
  <a class="btn btn-navbar pull-left">Left Text</a>
  <a class="btn btn-navbar pull-left">Left Text 2</a>
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
      <a class="brand" href="#" style="margin:0 auto; float: none;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XlPrrVD.png" style="height:30px;">    
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-navbar pull-right">Right Text</a>
</div>
```

I want the brand image to stay centered no matter what - even if there are several links on both sides of it.

Comment: The issue is that the menu items floating to the left of the `.navbar-inner` `div` are constricting its available width. That makes the "center" of the `div` shift to the right.

Comment: How can I have left and right elements while keeping the brand div centered then?

Comment: (Hack alert) Maybe give this a try: http://jsbin.com/efagoj/103

Comment: You could do as Donovan says if all it will contain is an image. If you want other content in there too, you could have it `position: absolute` with a full width and place it under the links. http://jsbin.com/efagoj/110/edit Although, doing this would take it out of the flow, so if the window is small enough, the image will show up under the links...

Comment: Thanks, any downside to the hack?

Comment: Good question about possible downsides. Obviously, it's never best practice to use hacks in production code. However, this does seem to work in Chrome, FF and recent IE. Of course, there could be unforeseen issues.

Comment: Just edited my response for one potential downside if you didn't see it. As far as other potential downsides go (related to my solution)... pretty much they're all related to it showing up under the content and being out of the page flow. So, it could potentially get cut off by the window. If there are links in it and somewhere down the line all of its ancestors are removed from the stacking order, it will show up under the page and not be clickable (which may be difficult to debug for someone without knowledge of stacking order).

Comment: That sounds good! I should be able to use @media to make modifications based on device width, correct?

Comment: You should be able to, I've also got another solution that might be more acceptable, posting in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution may be more acceptable than taking it out of the flow of the page. So if you have two floating containers, one on the left and one on the right, both of equal width, then the `div` in the center should be positioned correctly for centering.

http://jsbin.com/efagoj/116/edit

This however requires enough width on the page to look right. Plus you'd have to make sure both the left and right are always the same width if the navbar is ever changed... So the position absolute with @media queries might be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your `<img/>` and add this css

```
.navbar{
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/XlPrrVD.png") top center no-repeat;
  background-size:100 30px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/efagoj/101/

and code http://jsbin.com/efagoj/101/watch?html,css,js,output

if you want keep your code to add link on your `<img/>`

add .imgCenter on you image and this css

```
.imgCenter{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  width:100px;
  margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Comment: This is nice, however, I'd like for it to remain a link. Other ideas?

Comment: I have refresh link. You can add `position:absolute` and center image like this.